# Recreating the new Apple product browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have been working on recreating apple's new product browser as seen on their [mac](http://www.apple.com/uk/mac) and [iPod](http://www.apple.com/uk/ipod) pages.

So far I have got this far http://jsfiddle.net/xvzjY/3/

The problem is I cannot get the 1 by 1 element exiting in the same way they enter. I have removed the code I wrote to try and emulate this as it interfered with the entry function. Can anyone figure out how to make this as authentic as possible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bounceholder = 0;
    var delayact = 0;
    $('.bouncetabs a').click(function(){
        $('.bouncetabs a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        if($(this).index('.bouncetabs a') < bounceholder) { var backwards = 1 }
        else { var backwards = 0 }

        bounceholder = $(this).index('.bouncetabs a');
        var bounceoffset = 0;

        if($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 6){ var bounceoffset = 0;}
        else if($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 5){ var bounceoffset = 72;}
        else if($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 4){ var bounceoffset = 144;}
        else if($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 3){ var bounceoffset = 216;}
        else if($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 2){ var bounceoffset = 288;}

        $('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ')').prevAll().each(function(i) {
            $('li', this).delay(150).animate({left: -200, top:0, opacity:0, leaveTransforms:true}, 600);
        });
        $('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ')').nextAll().each(function(i){
            $('li', this).delay(150).animate({left: +1000, top:0, opacity:0, leaveTransforms:true}, 600);
        });

            if(backwards == 1) {
                bounceoffset = 800 - bounceoffset;
                $($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').get().reverse()).each(function(i){
                  delay = (i + 1) * 250;
                  $(this).delay(delay).animate({left: bounceoffset, top:0, opacity:0.6, leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:400, queue:true});
                  bounceoffset -= 160;
                });
            }
            else {
                $('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').each(function(i){
                  delay = (i + 1) * (250 * delayact);
                  $(this).delay(delay).animate({left: bounceoffset, top:0, opacity:0.6, leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:400, queue:true});
                  bounceoffset += 160;
                });
            }
            delayact = 1;

    return false
    });

});
```